# What to use for running a php script for multiple users?

Tags: php, multithreading, web

I got some code in php script (example.php). This script runs about 30-60 seconds and does some actions for one user.

Example.php runs atm only for 1 given user, what is the best way for looping over my users table and running this script for each one?

The script gets called now every ~5 minutes, this should stay the same expect it should be started for each user.

I am running PHP7.2 on my webserver and i tried it already with cronjobs. This works but only for the one hard-coded user. If I would put the loop for all users into this one script the running time would be to enormous. I tried to install pthreads on plesk but this also is a bit complicated.

As said it works for one user already but I dont know whats the best way to let it run for all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `shell_exec` for executing the php file with the various `user_id` as a parameter.

```
shell_exec("/path/to/php /path/to/example.php '".$user_id."' 'alert' >> /path/to/your_log/result.log &");
```

the symbol *&* is important because it is tell the server to run this process as background.

OR

You can implement some queue system and pushing job as background process.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll try this later, this could be the solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently what I do when I need to run many PHP scripts in parallell is using a queue system like [bernard](https://github.com/bernardphp/bernard) on one hand you will have a launcher script that will push tasks into a queue (implemented for example on a Redis server). This is what would be done by the cron job. Every 5 minutes will call the launcher script, that will push one job per user to the queue, as you can push parameters to the queue, you can push the task with the user as the parameter.

On the other hand you have as many listeners as you want, the listener processes can be managed by [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) for example. Those listeners are waiting for a task to process from the queue independently, whenever they find a task they could do, they would perform it so this way you can peform as many tasks concurrenly as you wish.

The implementation of what you do at the moment with your user is what would be written in the listener code. This is just a simple way to explain the whole thing, I encourage you to read through the [bernard documentation](https://bernard.readthedocs.io/), it would be much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

my solution would be to loop over all your users and call the function from within the loop but if you say that takes to long, i don't see a way of speeding it up

i don't think there is a way to give a user along through a cronjob.
do you have a code snippet for us to look at?

Comment: Thank you all for answering

The cronjob for now just opens the URL http://example.com/script.php, i use a external cronjob service for this at the moment (https://cron-job.org). 
In the script the $user_id is hardcoded.
``

Comment: *EDIT

Thank you all for answering

The cronjob for now just opens the URL http://example.com/example.php, i use a external cronjob service for this at the moment (https://cron-job.org). 
In the script the $user_id is hardcoded. Its no problem to implement it to give the parameter via URL, but the problem is how run this php file via another script or something like that which gets called by cron-job.org.

I would also like to implement it all on my server but i dont know a proper way for it without that external service!